# discord js getting args from user message and using them in variables shows up as undefined

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, discord, discord.js

I'm using user input from messages starting with prefix to execute commands but get undefined when I try to use the values inside my code

```
 let args;

client.on('message', async message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }
  
  args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  console.log("args: ", args); // logs out correctly
  let x = args[1];
  console.log("args[1]: ", x) // this will give undefined
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'generate') {
    console.log("generate command used");
    await replyWithInvite(message);
  }
})
```

also using args array in a function like `replyWithInvite()` will result in all the args values showing up as undefined, how can I use these values?

EDIT:

server response to my message:
[image]

This is my whole code, I'm trying to generate a certain number of discord invites according to the second argument number

```
    let args;

client.on('message', async message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("this did register");
  args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  console.log("args: ", args); // here i get values
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'generate') {
    console.log("generate command used");
    await replyWithInvite(message);
  }
})

async function replyWithInvite(message) {
  let invite = [];
  console.log("args1: ", await args[1]); // here I get undefined
  count = 1;
  message.reply("Here are your 1 time use invites, which expire in 10 minutes: ")
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    invite.push(await message.channel.createInvite(
    {
      maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000, // maximum time for the invite, in milliseconds
      maxUses: 1 // maximum times it can be used
    }
    ))
    message.channel.send(invite ? `${invite[i]}` : "There has been an error during the creation of the invite.");
  }
  message.channel.send("That's it!")
}
```

I hardcoded the count value in the function so that I get a result, but I can't find a way to use args, I'm using Heroku as a host

Comment: What exactly is the message you are sending? I cannot reproduce, but if you tell me what you send, I might be able to.

Comment: @MrMythical well I'm sending for example something like "!generate 35" where 35 can be any number, I will include a server response in my question

Comment: Is that the exact message? The entire content of it?

Comment: yes, I added the server response too

Comment: I still cannot reproduce. Is this all the code in your message event? Are you using the variable `args` somewhere else?

Comment: I added the whole codebase, except of login tokens and requires, in the first instance I get the values, but when I run my invite link generator function I get undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by the time you call the function, you already shifted the array. Since arrays are 0-indexed, you have to use `args[0]` instead!

```js
async function replyWithInvite(message) {
  //...
  console.log("args1: ", args[0]) //should give value
  //...
}
```

In case there are any questions about where it was shifted, here it was shifted

```js
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: this seems to work, but I don't get why would the array shift? Could you please explain why this happens?

Comment: You shifted it before calling the function (in message callback)